# pipeline buffer encountered an invalid row index error script task component ssis

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

in my Transformation Script task component  i am performing some transformation on input columns and based on that assiging the values to output columns and insertin the data to oledb detination table.

but i am getting this error which says:
pipeline buffer encountered an invalid row index

Comment: Please post your Script Component code.

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic832762-147-1.aspx

Comment: To get a better help. Post your code